# Pass Validation on Form Fields Before Friendly ID Creation - Custom

Tags: validation, url, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I currently have two models

**Location** and **Product**

I have it configured that when a record is created in my production model, it creates a custom url based on the information it has gather from the location selected during the product creation

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  name_changed? or location_id_changed?
end

def slug_candidates
 [
  [location.media_type, location.state, location.name, :name, :sku]
 ]
end
```

What I am currently testing is when a user decides NOT to fill out those very important fields, for it to throw an error message before creating

```
validates :name, presence: true
validates :sku, presence: true
validates :location_id, presence: true
```

What is happening in my case, is that it overlooks that validator and first tries to create the slug. If I remove the custom attributes to the url creation and list as

```
def slug_candidates
   [
    [:name, :sku]
   ]
end
```

it will work fine, running the field validators first. Assuming because those two are attributes on the given model directly.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I need for the validators to be picked up first since it contains all the relevant information for the url.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
def slug_candidates
    if self.location_id.nil?
       self.errors.add(:location_id)
    else
       [
          [location.media_type, location.state, location.name, :name, :sku]
       ]
   end
end
```